# How to pass & merge two models in MVC3 in Index and Edit View (strongly bound)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

Model/Db Entity Relationship (baseline placeholder literary content):

```
public class TitlePercent
{
   public int TitleName; 
   public decimal Percentage;      
}

public class TitleMonthly
{
   public string Month;
   public int Val;
}
```

Cardinality => 1 TitlePercent to * TitleMonthly

Illustrated View (proposed):

```
_____________________________
Name  | % ||  Jan | Feb |
_____________________________
Title1 2%     23    343
Title2 3%     343   3434
_____________________________
```

Controller (proposed):

```
    // Need view and edit   
    public ViewResult ViewTitlePercentAndTitleMontly()
    {
        return View(db.<NotSureWhatWouldGoHere>.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult EditTitlePercentAndTitleMontly(int id)
    {
        return View(db.<NotSureWhatWouldGoHere>.Find(id));
    }
```

Razor View (proposed psuedo):
...View and Edit
    @model MVC3.Models.TitlePercent
    @model2 MVC3.Models.TitleMonthly

```
1. For Index View to show the grid not sure how to mash this up (like the grid)
   - Perhaps build this in the controller but not sure how to build and pass that to the view as
     I have had not dealt with multiple models as relationships.
2. For Edit View need to figure out how to bind to a model similar to:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TitleName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Percentage)

    foreach TitleMonthly in TitlePercentag
    {
       @* Iterate and bind somehow *@
       @Html.EditorFor(model2 => model2.Month)
       @Html.EditorFor(model2 => model2.Val)
    }
    ???
```

Sorry for the lack of details and pseudo code but I just haven't had to deal with multiple models especially if they are related/dependencies of each other and and in which the grid view can be created by  joined classes/tables....then if you want to edit a row (combo of both classes then how can you bind all relationships to text boxes based on those two class models)?

Again, I'll submit to ridicule on this one but any information and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mariah, this was a stumbling block for me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you use something called a `ViewModel` which is a very specific model designed for a view. You would populate that model with information from your data model and then pass that to the View. it doesn't have to have a 1:1 structure either which allows you to have a lot more information or a lot less, depending on your needs.

For your editor model you could create a ViewModel similar to:

```
public class TitleEditingViewModel { 
    public TitlePercent TitlePercent {get;set;}
    public ICollection<TitleMonthly> MonthlyTitles {get;set;}
}
```

You would then populate that model however you want in the controller and then pass the model into the view.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TitlePercent.TitleName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TitlePercent.Percentage)

@foreach titleMonthly in Model.MonthlyTitles {
   @Html.EditorFor(model => titleMonthly.Month)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => titleMonthly.Val)
}
```

Comment: Hi BuildStarted: How can I map this custom view?  I get nulls coming back from my view?